# Что-то поменялось в порядке объявлений скриптов.

Tags: html, javascript

Доброе всем время.
Это заговор, или я что-то где-то недочитал,
Был у меня хороший **рабочий** html (несколько месяцев назад), с объявленными в нем скриптами:

```
…
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
…
```

И вот я на днях открыл этот html и обнаружил, что скрипты вообще не работают. Я и туда и сюда…
Оказалось, что для отработки скриптов нужно поменять порядок объявлений на:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript3.js"></script>
```

И все будет ОК.
Это правда так? Или у меня что-то опять не так?

Comment: да jquery нужно подключить до того, как вы его начнете использовать в своем скрипте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок к коде не гарантирует выполнение по этому же порядку.
Проблема довольно занозистая, [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/182310/) можно о ней почитать и, вероятно, найти наиболее удобное для вас решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Всем спасибо :-), а то думал совсем все плохо...